# Automatically correct invalid XML?

Tags: c#, xml, ssis, xsd, schema

I am currently using SSIS on a project where I need to verify the correct XML file structure. In particular, I have to check that there is no missing tag in the XML file and if so, I have to reassemble this line without tag.
I'll give you an example to better understand.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<DATA>0000000061E82D821590010000409525CD</DATA> 
<DATA>0000000061E82D8C163001000140AD0DF6</DATA> 
<DATA>0000000061E82D9616E301000240776CAB</DATA>
<DATA> 0000000061E82DA0178001000340C56B6</DATA> 
<DATA>0000000061E82DAA188001000440C0C7CB</DATA>
 0000000061E82DDAEA4001000540BB9A276
</catalog>
```

For example in the above XML there is a `<DATA>` tag missing. I have no influence on the creation of the XML.
How could I notice that a `<DATA>` tag is missing (the number of data lines is not fixed), and subsequently retrieve that line where there is no tag ?

For example in the above xml there is a `<DATA>` tag missing. I have no influence on the creation of the XML.

The solution can be a suite of SSIS components or a c# script.

Comment: [XML Schema validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xml-schema-xsd-validation-with-xmlschemaset). => or with [Linq 2 Xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/validate-xsd).

Comment: _"I have no influence on the creation of the XML."_ - You can use the linked tech to validate the XML. _But_ I'd strongly advise to _not_ try and "fix" broken XML. Just reject the input. Have the source fix its output. Even if that means _you need to push back_. And don't let things count like "Yeah but it's _obvious_ that it's just a missing ... " - No. The input is invalid. Period.

Comment: @Fildor has a good point, but sometimes you're stuck with the input you're given and recalcitrance will just make trouble for you. In that case, if the schema is known, you could write a state-machine-based parser (or, possibly, even find one out there) that can kick out tags missing their closing tags.

Comment: *Actually*, if your XML has line breaks, and each tag is on a single line, couldn't you just filter out any lines that don't end in ">"?  Or is the real XML too complex for that?

Comment: _"couldn't you just filter out any lines that don't end in ">"?"_ - I really think that would make things worse: Then you are silently dropping input data.

Comment: I should have said "filter in" rather than "filter out!"  I meant, as the questioner said, retrieve the lines that are missing closing tags.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to automatically correct invalid XML in the general case.

**Terminology correction**

> For example in the above XML there is a `<DATA>` tag missing.

There is not ***a*** `<DATA>` tag missing.  You probably mean that there are supposed to be *begin **and** end* `DATA` tags surrounding `0000000061E82DDAEA4001000540BB9A276`. The difference is significant because if there were only a single tag missing, the "XML" would not be *well-formed*.  If a schema says that a `catalog` element may only have `DATA` children, then the XML is not *valid*.

- See [Well-formed vs Valid XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085) for a detailed description of this important distinction.

  - If you actually had to try to read *not-well-formed* "XML," you could try the suggestions listed in  [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085).

**Don't try to automatically correct invalid XML**

Best practice is to reject the input and force the sender/creator to fix the document.  The entire *raison d'être* for a schema is to express the invariants that can be relied upon to process the data.  Violating those invariants means all bets are off.

**Don't be seduced by the superficial simplicity of peep-hole repair ideas**

Every repair idea implies an assumption about the data that is not expressed in the schema, which would be bad because:

- There should be a clearly and explicitly expressed definition of validity and
- The assumptions

  - will likely not be expressed unambiguously.
  - may not be expressed at all.
  - may be incomplete or entirely incorrect.
  - will probably go unconfirmed because an errant producer that
    can/will not fix validity against a schema is unlikely to be
    able to assess the validity of an assumption over all data
    that it is, or could be, sending over all time.

### See also

- [How to remove invalid XML elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40974762/290085)